# SQL Server 2008 on localhost: Connection continually refused

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The problem I am having is that I keep receiving the

> (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

error every time I try to connect to the database.

I can see the database in SQL Server Manager Studio and have created a login for it by right clicking the `security folder->new->login` and entering a username and password with SQL Server authentication. I can also see the `SQLSERVER (SQLSERVERDB)` process running in the services window.

The connection string in my Web.config file is

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="MainConnString" connectionString="Data Source=MEETING-ROOM\SQLSERVERDB,48006;Initial Catalog=Palace_Live;
          User ID=Palace_Live;Password=p@l@c310!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

- The server name/instance is: `MEETING-ROOM\SQLSERVERDB`
- The database is called `Palace_Live`
- User/Pass is `Palace_Live / p@l@c310!`

I know the issue relates to the connection string as if I change the Data Source parameter to say Googl.com I receive a different error message.

I can't see what steps I have missed or what I am doing wrong. Could anyone help point me in the right direction as to what I might be missing

I am using IIS7 and SQL Server 2008 locally on a windows 7 32bit machine.

Comment: If what I have performed above is standard and should work, could someone please comment and let me know so. Thanks

Comment: Why are you specifying port 48006?? Is that a change you've made knowing what you're doing?? The default SQL Server port would be 1433 - try just leaving that out - does that work?? `Server=MEETING-ROOM\SQLSERVERDB;database=Palace_Live;User ID=Palace_Live;Password=p@l@c310!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`

Comment: @marc_s Thank you, that was it. That was the connection string as it was given to me, I had no idea that the port number was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you specifying port 48006?? Is that a change you've made knowing what you're doing?? The default SQL Server port would be 1433.

If you try to just leave out the non-standard port - does that work for you??

```
Server=MEETING-ROOM\SQLSERVERDB;database=Palace_Live;User ID=Palace_Live;Password=p@l@c310!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

Answer (score 2):

As well as creating a Login to SQL Server have you added a User to the database(s) you want to access? This is usually done automatically when you create the Login when you give it access to specified databases, but can be done manually after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Try pinging: `MEETING-ROOM\SQLSERVERDB`

And if it gives you a response use the IP Address directly, also ensure that the Server does not have a firewall rule blocking incoming traffic on Port 48006.

Also ensure SQL Server is allowing Windows Authentication and SQL Server authentication.  This can be done by right clicking on the database in Management Studio and going to properties and Security.

Answer (score 0):

i know the question, the problem is not appear on database, is the IIS7.0.
there is a service account ,you need change it network in pool.
my english not good,if you also can't slove,please send me email:mjjjj2001@163.com